# Transfer Existing website to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, dreamweaver, file-transfer, transfer

I built a website from scratch using Dreamweaver. Now my boss would like to transfer the site to Wordpress. There is a lot of documentation on Wordpress, but I am finding a lot of information to contradict what I am seeing on the Wordpress site. I would like to know how I would go about transferring my website's html/css to Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use some migration template for WP like this one on [Github](https://github.com/sirjonathan/migration-theme). I think that pure template is the best example for starting with Wordpress.

Comment: Could you explain to me what this is doing? I do not have the option for a template. My boss wants the site I built for them.

Comment: It's something you're going to need to google and find out the correct file structure. It would take forever to explain on an answer here and would be nearly impossible. It's as simple as googling `How to make a wordpress theme from scratch`

Comment: Migration theme is like a frame for your existing static page. It defines all required by Wordpress constraints, so when you fill down those files with your content it could be imported by WP as a regular template.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not much experience in Wordpress, you should hire a service to do that. Learning Wordpress well enough for migrate html to Wordpress will take you lot of time with problems.